# elasticsearch query is giving results very slow on a simple query

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql

I am using *elasticsearch* to perform some aggregations. Everything used to work fine, but currently I have 2 million docs in an index. I am performing a very simple search query `list all documents` in a given `type` of a given `index`.

```
{
"size":100000,
"query":
      {"match_all":{}
  }
}
```

This query is very slow and gives about `300k` hits. **What could be the possible reasons for it?**
**NOTE: i am having 2G ram . 2 cores**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get a response with 100.000 documents in it. This is just too much. Elasticsearch is intended for paging. Paging means fetch in small chunks. You try to fetch a bulk of 100.000. There is a reason why it defaults with a size of 10.

Comment: thanks for response i found out that's the main issue was.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out that this configuration is enough for my needs that is searching over 2 million documents. i was having a wrong configuration and also the method of simply doing `match_all` is not correct even if we have 2 million docs performing a search based on some criteria would be very fast.